# Is it appropriate to cross-post questions from other StackExchange sites here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There are many questions that could be on-topic on more than one StackExchange site (for example, some questions on Travel.StackExchange would almost make more sense here). Is it acceptable to cross-post an exact question from one SE site to another, when it would be on-topic for both? Or is it better to make a mod request for migration to Outdoors.SE? Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been [discussed on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65931/172958). The accepted answer is as follows:

> Cross posting is fine, provided:
>
> 1. You respect the differences in the audiences at the different sites;
> 2. You allow some time to pass between successive questions, and update them in the light of the answers previously received; and
> 3. Really the first point again, you should have an idea what the new site offers in terms of expertise to crack your question that the previous site did not.
>
> Usenet-style forum spamming is, I hardly need to say, bad.

So asking the same thing is fine, but exact copy-pasting may not be appropriate, you should at least try to tailor it to the site.

As far as migrating, If a question is on-topic on a site, it is not migrated even if it would be on-topic on another site.